# Doctests that contain string literals

Tags: python, comments, doctest, python-2.4

I have a unit test that I'd like to write for a function that takes XML as a string.  It's a doctest and I'd like the XML in-line with the tests.  Since the XML is multi-line, I tried a string literal within the doctest, but no success.  Here's simplified test code:

```
def test():
  """
  >>> config = \"\"\"\
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <test>
    <data>d1</data>
    <data>d2</data>
  </test>\"\"\"
  """

if __name__ == "__main__":
  import doctest
doctest.testmod(name='test')
```

The error I get is

```
File "<doctest test.test[0]>", line 1
         config = """  <?xml version="1.0"?>
                                            ^
     SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string
```

I've tried many combinations and can't seem to get this to work.  It's either this or a "inconsistent leading whitepsace" error that I get.  Any suggestions?  I'm using python 2.4 (and no, there's no possibility of upgrading).

Comment: Have you tried putting in the `...` continuation prompts that the interactive shell uses?

Comment: I don't have python2.4 to test, but using three apostrophes ''' inside to avoid the \" bits and adding the "... " prefixes works for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This code works, e.g. with Python 2.7.12 and 3.5.2:

```
def test():
  """
  >>> config = '''<?xml version="1.0"?>
  ... <test>
  ...   <data>d1</data>
  ...   <data>d2</data>
  ... </test>'''
  >>> print(config)
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <test>
    <data>d1</data>
    <data>d2</data>
  </test>

  """

if __name__ == "__main__":
  import doctest
doctest.testmod(name='test')
```